# PC is not detecting Nexus 5 after revoking USB debugging authorizations

Tags: nexus-5, usb-debugging

I accidentally revoked USB debugging authorizations for my PC, and now it is not detecting my Nexus 5. It worked fine before this. I have USB debugging already enabled and tried disabling and renabling it, but it did not help.

Comment: Have you restarted your phone and PC before trying again?
And how are you connecting: via terminal/console, via Eclipse or Android Studio...?